# SwiftUI 2 lifecycle - handle custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Until now we were able to handle custom URL schemes that launch the app using `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`. But how is this possible using the new lifecycle?

I tried adding an `@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor` with the `application:openURL:options:` function but that is never called. The closest I've got is using the Environment's scenePhase but that only tells the state of the scene (active, background etc.), not the incoming URL.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`onOpenURL(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:)) modifier either in the body of you `App` or `Scene` or on views in your hierachy. The modifier gets called multiple times as well, so you could set the state for each view individually. With that your `AppDelegate` no longer needs to know your whole navigagion, which is great.